# Extracting all words after specified words until end of sentence

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

I need to extract all words after the  following words until the end of the sentence `(/[Ee]ach+/) ([tag:NN]+|[tag:NNS]+) (/has+/|/have+/)` but I am getting error in line number 13, below is my code:

```
 1  String file="Each campus has one club. Each programme has a unique code, title, level and   duration.";
 2  Properties props = new Properties();
 3  props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
 4  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
 5  Annotation document = new Annotation(file);
 6  pipeline.annotate(document);
 7  List<CoreLabel> tokens = new ArrayList<CoreLabel>();

 8  List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
 9  for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) 
10  {
11      for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) 
12         tokens.add(token); 

13      TokenSequencePattern pattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile("(/[Ee]ach+/) ([tag:NN]+|[tag:NNS]+) (/has+/|/have+/) [A-Z]");
14      TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(tokens);
15      while( matcher.find()){
16          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, matcher.group()); 
17          String matched = matcher.group();
18      }
19      tokens.removeAll(tokens);
20  }
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: the expected output is. "Each campus has one club" in first sentence and "Each programme has a unique code, title, level and   duration" in the second sentence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Stanford TokensRegex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512203/how-to-use-stanford-tokensregex)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this regex:

```
(?i)each[^.]+[.]
```

The regex as Java String:

```
"(?i)each[^.]+[.]"
```

And the Java code to use it:

```
String file = "Each campus has one club. Each programme has a unique code, title, level and   duration.";
    String pattern = "(?i)each[^.]+[.]";
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(file);
    while (matcher.find()) {            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The slashes you see around regular expressions in many languages, eg

```
/someregex/
```

have nothing whatsoever to do with regular expressions: The slashes are an *application language* artefact, and java is not one of the languages that uses them.

Once you strip off those slashes, and fix your regex alteration, and remove incorrectly intentioned character classes, and a few other tweaks, this regex should work:

```
([Ee]ach|tag:NNS?|ha(s|ve)) +\w+
```

Comment: The problem still same, could you help please?

Comment: Maybe show sample input and expected match - it would help a lot

Comment: if the input is "Please cerate a database which containing the following, each employee has name, address and telephone number." the output should be "each employee has name, address and telephone number."

Comment: So, you want all the input from the first occurrence of any of the words "each", "has" or "have" to the next end of sentence?